# How to check if an associative array has an empty or null value

Tags: php, arrays

In the following associative array

```
$array = array(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 
)
```

how can you determine if a given key has an empty (or null) value? I used

```
if(empty($array[$value]))
```

and

```
if(isset($array[$value])) && $array[$value] !=='')
```

When using `empty` I also get `false` for the first array value which is zero and  `isset` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: I'm doing: `foreach($array as $key => $value) { if(is_null($array[$value])) { echo 'NULL'; } }` but it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $array[/*key must be here*/];

Answer (score 39, accepted):

use [`array_key_exists()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) and [`is_null()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php) for that. It will return `TRUE` if the key exists and has a value far from `NULL`

Difference:

```
$arr = array('a' => NULL);

var_dump(array_key_exists('a', $arr)); // -->  TRUE
var_dump(isset($arr['a'])); // -->  FALSE
```

So you should check:

```
if(array_key_exists($key, $array) && is_null($array[$key])) {
    echo "key exists with a value of NULL";
}
```

Comment: `array_key_exists` will return true for the empty values, since the key does exist.

Comment: @Paulpro And that's exactly in question

Comment: Oh I see. I thought you meant that array_key_exists will return false for an empty value. Now that you've explained it in more detail +1

Comment: +1 That's a really cleaver solution, although it doesn't cover the case of an empty string or some other `empty` conditions. I think the question need some clarification on what should be considered empty for validation.

Comment: How about the exact example I've given? Key [2] has no value, that's what I'm trying to do, check if a given key has a value.

Comment: @bikey77 Then my answer should do *excatly* what you want

Comment: It may work if values are null but not when they are empty. In my example, if you do a var_dump for $array you'll see that the value for the second element is false, not null.

Comment: What is empty for you? An empty string? An empty array? (Note that you not told that so far)

Comment: Empty is when there's no value at all, not even null. At least that's my conclusion after var_dump returning false for values 2, 4.

Comment: Than it is NULL (that's the meaning of NULL).. note that the statements `$a;` and `$a = NULL;`  are the same

Answer (score 23):

Looked at all the answers and I don't like them. Isn't this much simpler and better? It's what I am using:

```
  if (in_array(null, $array, true) || in_array('', $array, true)) {
    // There are null (or empty) values.
  }
```

Note that setting the third parameter as true means strict comparison, this means 0 will not equal null - however, neither will empty strings ('') - this is why we have two conditions. Unfortunately the first parameter in in_array has to be a string and cannot be an array of values.

Comment: `if (in_array('', $_POST)) { // Contains empty values. }`

Comment: In PHP 7.0.1(Windows version) this is malfunctioning

Comment: `$arr = ['a', 0, 'b'];
print_r (in_array(null, $arr)) ;` 
returns 1 with this code.

Comment: Good point, if we set true as the third parameter in in_array it is treated as strict comparison and hence the 0 will not be recorded as null.

Comment: If you don't care about validating keys, only the values, in an associative Array, use `$array = array_values($origArray)` before the answer provided.

Answer (score 5):

PHP [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) return values states:

> Returns FALSE if var exists and has a non-empty, non-zero value. Otherwise returns TRUE.
>
> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> "" (an empty string)
>
> 0 (0 as an integer)
>
> 0.0 (0 as a float)
>
> "0" (0 as a string)
>
> NULL
>
> FALSE
>
> array() (an empty array)
>
> $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

From your array example I take it as you want to exclude the **0 as an integer**. If that's the case this would do the trick:

```
<?php
    $array = array(0, 1, '', 2, '');

    foreach ($array as $value) {
        echo (empty($value) && 0 !== $value) ? "true\n" : "false\n";
    }
```

If you want to exclude other conditions that `empty` considers just negate them in that condition. Take in account that this might not be the optimal solution if you want to check other values.

Comment: (empty($value) && '0' !== $value) adding a quote/double quote on zero works for me.

Comment: @IvorySantos, `'0'` and `"0"` are string representations of zero and not an integer representation, it really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: `$value` is guaranteed to be declared, therefore `empty()` is inappropriate (doing too much).

Comment: @mickmackusa, great input. `empty()` is described in the official documentation as "Determine whether a variable is empty", which suites the op question. Nevertheless, I agree with your take that's its doing too much is this case, as its an all-rounder function, that's why I have that last sentence on my answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( !isset($array[$key]) || $array[$key] == "" || is_null($array[$key]) )
{
    //given key does not exist or it has "" or NULL value
}
```

Comment: Writing `is_null()` after `!isset()` reveals a lack of understanding of `isset()`.  Also `is_null()` after `== ""` revels  lacck of understanding regarding loose comparisons. https://3v4l.org/Tc0Uv  This answer is recommending techniques which readers should not be copying or learning from.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($array as $i => $v) {
    if(null === $v) {
        // this item ($array[$i]) is null
    }
}
```

...or, for a given key:

```
if(null === $array[2]) {
     // this item ($array[2]) is null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Potentially this could be cleaner if I knew how the array was constructed, but, having the assumption that you can have both empty strings, or nulls in the array, and you want to account for values of 0 --> here's what I'd do:

```
if (is_null($array[$key]) || (string)$array[$key] == '')
```

Here's a little bit of test code showing it in action with an array that has both 0, null, an empty string, and non-zero integers...

```
$array = array(0,1,null,2,'');
print_r($array);

foreach ($array as $key => $val) {
         if (is_null($array[$key]) || (string)$array[$key] == '') {
           echo $key.", true\n";
         }
}
```

As for using isset() -- an empty string is consider to be set. Which may be what you're running into (aside from 0 being considered empty) Compare with this usage:

```
$foo = array(0,1,null,2,'');

print_r($foo);
foreach ($foo as $key => $val) {
        if (isset($foo[$key])) {
                echo $key.", true\n";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 function is_empty($data){
    $is_empty = true;
    foreach ($data as $val){
       if(is_array($val)){
          $is_empty = is_empty($val);
       }else{
          if(!empty($val)){
             $is_empty = false;
             break;
          }
       }
    }
    return $is_empty;
 }
```

Comment: This snippet is missing its educational explanation.  Why should someone use this snippet versus other advice on this page?  Why use `!empty()` on `$val` which is guaranteed to be declared?  What if `$val = 0`?

Answer (score 0):

I know this old but still none of them directly answer the question:

> how can you determine if `a given key` `has an empty` (`or null`) `value`?

```php
if ( empty($array[$value]) || is_null($array[$value]) )
```

This answers the question exactly. It says if array value is empty or array value is null.